# Best practices on Navigation Drawer use

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I was reading about `Navigation Drawer` and it was not until now that I came into this question: If my top views are going to be accessible through the `Navigation Drawer`, should I code each of them as `Fragments` or as `Activities`?

I want to know the way it was intended to be used, with `Fragments` or with `Activities`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way is to use `Fragment`s.

When you click on an item, you should always replace the `Fragment` of your Main `Activity` without adding the elements in the Back Stack. This will create a seamless dynamic navigation instead of launching new activities and managing the drawer into them.

Here are some references

- [Google's design guidelines](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)
- [Google's development guidelines](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)